# How to make a GET request in Go Fiber to an API endpoint?

Tags: go, go-fiber, fasthttp

How to make a GET request in [GO Fiber](https://docs.gofiber.io/). I saw Fiber [client](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/client/) but there is no working example code there. Could anyone kindly show me how to do that?
suppose there is a API endpoint https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts How can I get the data from that endpoint using the Fiber [client](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/client/)?

Comment: Are you intending do http calls to server spawned by go fiber?

Comment: No, I want to create an HTTP request by using Fiber [Client](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/client/). Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The client feature has released with [v2.6.0](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/releases/tag/v2.6.0). And see the implemention commit at [here](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/pull/1177)

Also see [client.go](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/master/client.go)

Here is the sample code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

type user struct {
    UserID int    `json:"userId"`
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Body   string `json:"body"`
}

func main() {
    request := fiber.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    request.Debug()

    // to set headers
    request.Set("header-token", "value")

    _, data, err := request.Bytes()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var users []user
    jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(data, &users)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, data := range users {
        fmt.Println("UserID : ", data.UserID)
        fmt.Println("Title : ", data.Title)
    }

}
```

You can use the other http methods as

```
fiber.Post()
fiber.Patch()
fiber.Put()
fiber.Delete()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your code sample. Can you please kindly show me how can I add Headers to this request?  Suppose I want to add  <Token> to the header how can I do that? Kindest Regards.

Comment: You can use [Set method](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/master/client.go#L218) of `Agent` struct. I have updated the answer.

Comment: See the [Header](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/master/client.go#L213) section, as it have more methods to add the headers with the request.

Comment: Dear @pratheesh-pc, Thank you so much for your Reply, As you see, statusCode, data, requestErr := request.Bytes() didn't contain a response Header, Is there any way to get the response header?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Renan Bastos(@renanbastos93). I got another working code example.

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)
type Posts struct {
    UserID int    `json:"userId"`
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Body   string `json:"body"`
}
type AllPosts []Posts

func getPosts(c *fiber.Ctx) (err error) {
    agent := fiber.AcquireAgent()
    agent.Request().Header.SetMethod("GET")
    agent.Request().SetRequestURI("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    err = agent.Parse()
    if err != nil {
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    var allPosts AllPosts
    statusCode, body, errs := agent.Bytes()
    if len(errs) > 0 {
        return c.Status(statusCode).JSON(errs)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &allPosts)
    if err != nil {
        return c.SendStatus(fiber.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    return c.JSON(allPosts)
}

func main() {
    f := fiber.New()
    f.Get("/", getPosts)
    err := f.Listen(":9000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: glad you got it working.